# Is it possible to have delegates marshalled as proxies when they are passed across to another AppDomain?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, appdomain, marshalbyrefobject

Somehow I assumed that delegates passed to another AppDomain would turn into a proxy as if it were an object derived from `MarshalByRefObject`. Unfortunately, it seems they don’t.

Let’s say in my code I have a class `MyClass` like this:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class MyClass
{
    public Func<Input, Output> SomeDelegate;
}

[Serializable]
public sealed class Input { ... }
[Serializable]
public sealed class Output { ... }
```

Now I need to pass an instance of `MyClass` to another AppDomain.

The problem is that the delegate stored in `SomeDelegate` may contain a reference to pretty much any method, including potentially a method on an instance of a type that is neither `[Serializable]` nor derived from `MarshalByRefObject`.

For the sake of this question, let’s assume that I cannot change the code that creates the delegate, nor can I make `MyClass` a `MarshalByRefObject`. It is, however, `[Serializable]`.

(Note that if `MyClass` contained a field of a type that derives from `MarshalByRefObject`, the object stored in that field would be turned into a proxy, while the rest of the class is serialized.)

Is there something I can do that will allow me to pass the class as serialized, but with the delegate turned into a proxy, just as it would be if it were a `MarshalByRefObject`? (Preferably in the setup of the AppDomain so that I don’t need to change `MyClass`, but suggestions that involve changing the class are welcome too as long as I don’t need to change the code that creates the delegate.)

Comment: In theory you could create an AOP wrapper that on the remote end serialized the data across to the hosting AppDomain and run the delegate. Bit complicated tho...You can look at either Windsor Castle's DynamicProxy or Unity's Interceptor to do this...

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it is not directly possible to make the delegate itself a proxy. [Delegates are always by-value objects for the purpose of remoting.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h8f0y3fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) I find that a strange design decision as I think it goes against the logical semantics of delegates, but that’s another matter.

To solve this, I had to wrap the delegate into a class that I can make a `MarshalByRefObject` so that it would be proxied. That class needs to have a method that is equivalent to invoking the delegate. To keep this clean, I decided to make that class private:

```
private sealed class myDelegateWrapper : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public Output Invoke(Input input)
    {
        return _delegate(input);
    }

    private Func<Input, Output> _delegate;

    public myDelegateWrapper(Func<Input, Output> dlgt)
    {
        _delegate = dlgt;
    }
}
```

Now I can instantiate this class in the setter of the delegate in `MyClass`:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class MyClass
{
    private Func<Input, Output> _someDelegate;

    public Func<Input, Output> SomeDelegate
    {
        get
        {
            return _someDelegate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                _someDelegate = null;
            else
                _someDelegate = new myDelegateWrapper(value).Invoke;
        }
    }
}
```

This is quite roundabout, but it fulfills all my criteria: The delegate can still be anything; it will be invoked remotely (because it will go through the proxied wrapper); and `MyClass` is still `[Serializable]` instead of a proxy.

In theory, one could write an extension method `Delegate.ToMarshalByRef()` which will do this dynamically with any delegate, but it would have to declare the wrapper class at runtime as it needs an `Invoke` method with the right signature.