# How to call arbitrary method from another AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, mono, appdomain

I'm making a plugin manager, which interfaces with third-party code. I would like the plugins to be reloadable at runtime and also access the third-party code (in the default AppDomain) from the plugins.

I tried to use AppDomains, but I haven't found a way to call *any* method without having to wrap each available method/object.

I've looked at a couple of questions, and for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48648246/2703239), the links in it and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18714459/2703239) gave some insight on how cross-AppDomain communication works.

I have successfully created a proxy class for a single method to be called in the default AppDomain thanks to the second answer, but this would require me to add one for each possible method call that would be called from a plugin.

I also tried to use the code with Action as the passed type, to allow the plugin to pass some code to be executed in the default AppDomain, but it failed with various errors. Here's my last attempt.

Main application:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class DelegateWrapper<T1>
{
    private Action<T1> _someDelegate;

    public Action<T1> SomeDelegate
    {
        get
        {
            return _someDelegate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                _someDelegate = null;
            else
                _someDelegate = new myDelegateWrapper(value).Invoke;
        }
    }

    private sealed class myDelegateWrapper : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public void Invoke(T1 input)
        {
            _delegate(input);
        }

        private Action<T1> _delegate;

        public myDelegateWrapper(Action<T1> dlgt)
        {
            _delegate = dlgt;
        }
    }
}


[Serializable]
public sealed class P
{
    public Action Action { get; }

    public P(Action action)
    {
        this.Action = action;
    }
}

private static readonly DelegateWrapper<P> PerformWrapper=new DelegateWrapper<P>();

public static void Init()
{
    PerformWrapper.SomeDelegate = p => p.Action();
}
```

Inside the new AppDomain, the Perform method is calling perform.SomeDelegate.

Plugin (also executing in the new AppDomain):

```
Perform(new P(() =>
{
    //Third-party code
}));
```

This results in an exception saying that it cannot find the plugin's assembly I loaded manually in the plugin AppDomain. I assume it's trying to load it in the default domain as well. Is there a way to get around it?

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Plugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies
```

Full stack trace here: https://pastebin.com/xZV7bXeV

Comment: the error is giving you a very good hint, did you place the Plugin.dll file in the same folder where the exe is, or in the current directory?

Comment: @knocte I have loaded the plugin already at that point manually and I don't want it to get loaded outside the app domain since then I can't reload it.

Comment: not sure i understand; anyway you should know that AppDomains are deprecated technology already because they're not supported in .NETCore AFAIK; you should just use MEF